mosquitto bad JSON interpretation subscriber
I am trying to publish a message in JSON via -m with a mosquitto publisher. The problem is that my subscriber receive the JSON message without the "" for every single key... so that the format is not JSON any more. Any solution?


I expect something like {"Location":14.647291} etc.

Please edit the question to show the full command you are running as text not images. Images are hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers and unsearchable. It also make it possible to copy/paste your commands to fix them in the answer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Wrap the message payload in single quotes. This will be the shell stripping the quotes.
e.g.
mosquitto_pub -t foo/bar -m '{ "hello": "world" }'

or double quotes and escape the internal ones
mosquitto_pub -t foo/bar -m "{ \"hello\": \"world\" }"


the last option worked, thank you very much!!
